# populate View Holder to Firebase object

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I'am trying to get my data from firebase to recycler view, but i get an error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: atoa.roomates, PID: 14648
   com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
       at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
       at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:161)
       at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:150)
       at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:190)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5768)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5801)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5037)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3260)
       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2788)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1835)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:725)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:616)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1835)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:725)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:616)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2881)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2237)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1537)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1180)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6558)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java
07-03 23:20:16.911 17904-17904/atoa.roomates:background_crash D/ResourcesManager: creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/atoa.roomates-2/base.apk
07-03 23:20:17.181 17904-17904/atoa.roomates:background_crash E/InstantRun: IO Error creating local socket at atoa.roomates
java.io.IOException: Address already in use
    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.bindLocal(Native Method)
    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.bind(LocalSocketImpl.java:306)
    at android.net.LocalServerSocket.<init>(LocalServerSocket.java:52)
    at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.<init>(Server.java:94)
    at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Server.create(Server.java:88)
    at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.onCreate(BootstrapApplication.java:358)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5007)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

This is my main activity:

```
public class Notes extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    RecyclerView mListMessages;
    Button sendMessageBtn;
    EditText userMessage;
    Firebase ref;
    String phoneNumber;
    int apartmentNumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        ref = new Firebase("my-firebase-site/items");
        sendMessageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
        mListMessages = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messageList);
        mListMessages.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mListMessages.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        userMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_input);

        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("appData", 0);
        apartmentNumber = preferences.getInt("apartmentNumber", 0);
        phoneNumber = preferences.getString("phoneNumber", null);

        sendMessageBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Timestamp t = new Timestamp(apartmentNumber);
        NotesModel note = new NotesModel(userMessage.getText().toString(),phoneNumber,t);
        ref.push().setValue(note);
        userMessage.setText("");
        userMessage.clearFocus();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NotesModel,NotesRecycleView.notesRecycle> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NotesModel, NotesRecycleView.notesRecycle>(
                NotesModel.class,
                R.layout.notes_item,
                NotesRecycleView.notesRecycle.class,
                ref
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(NotesRecycleView.notesRecycle notesRecycle, NotesModel n, int i) {

                //get current date and time
                Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                String ts = tsLong.toString();

                notesRecycle.getUserMessage().setText(n.getUserMessage());
                notesRecycle.getDateMessage().setText(n.getMessageDate().toString());
                notesRecycle.getPhonenumber().setText(n.getUserPhone());
            }
        };
        mListMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

this is my recycele view holder:

```
public class NotesRecycleView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesRecycleView.notesRecycle> {

    ArrayList<NotesModel> list;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    @Override
    public NotesRecycleView.notesRecycle onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roomate_list_item, parent , false);
        notesRecycle pvh = new notesRecycle(view);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(notesRecycle holder, int position) {
        NotesModel current = list.get(position);
        holder.userMessage.setText(current.getUserMessage());
        holder.Phonenumber.setText(current.getUserPhone());
        holder.dateMessage.setText(current.getMessageDate().toString());
    }

    public NotesRecycleView(ArrayList<NotesModel> list, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.list = list;
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class notesRecycle extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView userMessage;
        private TextView Phonenumber;
        private TextView dateMessage;

        public TextView getUserMessage() {
            return userMessage;
        }

        public TextView getPhonenumber() {
            return Phonenumber;
        }

        public TextView getDateMessage() {
            return dateMessage;
        }

        notesRecycle(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            userMessage = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.userMessage);
            Phonenumber = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.userPhone);
            dateMessage = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateMessage);

        }

    }
}
```

and this is my model:

```
public class NotesModel {

    public NotesModel(String userPhone, String userMessage, Timestamp messageDate) {
        this.userPhone = userPhone;
        this.userMessage = userMessage;
        this.messageDate = messageDate;
    }

    private String userPhone;
    private String userMessage;

    public Timestamp getMessageDate() {
        return messageDate;
    }

    public void setMessageDate(Timestamp messageDate) {
        this.messageDate = messageDate;
    }

    public String getUserPhone() {
        return userPhone;
    }

    public void setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
        this.userPhone = userPhone;
    }

    public String getUserMessage() {
        return userMessage;
    }

    public void setUserMessage(String userMessage) {
        this.userMessage = userMessage;
    }

    private Timestamp messageDate;
}
```

Comment: Try adding a no-argument constructor to `NotesModel`.

Comment: Yup ..as mentioned by @qbix .. Its because of no-argument constuctor. Try adding it.

Comment: thanks a lot!! @qbix

Comment: Adding no argument constructor didn't work for me :(